# A better logging design or some SQL magic?

Tags: php, sql, mysql, database-design, application-design

I'm knee deep in modifying some old logging code that i didn't write and wondering what you think of it. This is an event logger written in PHP with MySQL, that logs message like:

```
Sarah added a user, slick101
Mike deleted a user, slick101
Bob edited a service, Payment
```

Broken up like so:

```
Sarah [user_id] added a user [message], slick101 [reference_id, reference_table_name]
```

Into a table like this:

```
log
---
id
user_id
reference_id
reference_table_name
message
```

Please note that the "Bob" and "Payment" in the above example messages are Id's to other tables, not the actual names. A join is needed to get the names.

It looks like the "reference _ table _ name" is for finding the proper names in the correct table, since only the reference _ id is stored. This would probably be good if somehow i could join on a table name that stored in reference_table_name, like so:

```
select * from log l
join {{reference_table_name}} r on r.id = l.reference_id
```

I think I see where he was going with this table layout - how much better to have ids for statistics instead of a storing the entire message in a single column (which would require text parsing). Now I'm wondering..

**Is there a better way or is it possible to do the make-believe join somehow?**

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the join based on the modelling, you'd be looking at a two stage process:

1. Get the table name from LOG for a particular message
2. Use dynamic SQL by constructing the actual query as a string.  IE:

   "SELECT l.* FROM LOG l JOIN "+ tableName +" r ON r.id = l.reference_id"

There's not a lot of value to logged deletions because there's no record to join to in order to see what was deleted.

**How much history does the application need?**

Do you need to know who did what to a value months/years in the past?  If records are required, they should be archived & removed from the table.  If you don't need all the history, consider using the following audit columns on each table:

- ENTRY_USERID, NOT NULL
- ENTRY_TIMESTAMP, DATE, NOT NULL
- UPDATE_USERID, NOT NULL
- UPDATE_TIMESTAMP, DATE, NOT NULL

These columns allow you to know who created the record & when, and who last successfully updated it and when.  I'd create audit tables on a case by case basis, it just depends on what functionality the user needs.